# Hash Calculating Tools

Tags: windows-xp, calculator, hashing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File checksum calculator for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/104355/file-checksum-calculator-for-windows)

What are some simple one-click tools to calculate hash of any file?
For example: I'm looking for something simple like with **Right click on File > View Hash** Functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try [HashCheck Shell Extension](http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/) (Windows only) or [HashTab](http://implbits.com/HashTab.aspx) (Windows and Mac).  It extends the Windows Explorer file properties dialog, adding another tab containing the file's CRC32, MD5, and SHA1 hashes.

If you're running Linux, see the `md5sum` and `sha1sum` commands.  You could easily extend your window manager to add a shortcut on the file context window, passing the filename to these commands.